# Calculate sum of column using reference of other column in awk

Tags: bash, awk

I have a file which contains 2 column. first column contains some keyword and second contains its size. Keywords can be repeated like below:

```
data1 5
data2 7
data3 4
data2 6
data1 3
data2 8
```

I want to calculate sum of sizes which are bound with same keyword.

For example output of above data will be:

```
data1 8
data2 21
data3 4
```

Is it possible using awk?

If yes then kindly guide me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do  `awk` with array:

```
awk '{a[$1]+=$2} END {for (i in a) print i,a[i]}' file
data1 8
data2 21
data3 4
```

How it works
`a[$1]` this create array named `a` using field `#1` as reference.
`a[$1]+=$2` is the same as `a[$1]=a[$1]+$2` add value of field `#2` to the array `a[$1]`
`for (i in a)` loop trough all value in array `a[$1]`
`print i,a[i]` prints the array `i` and the value of array `a[i]`

Comment: @Yugendra Added some info about how this works.  I do suggest you read some basic `awk` commands and tutorials on the net :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep output in same order as the input then use this little longer awk:

```
awk '$1 in a{a[$1]+=$2; next} {b[++k]=$1; a[$1]=$2}
             END{for(i=1; i<=k; i++) print b[i], a[b[i]]}' file
data1 8
data2 21
data3 4
```

Comment: clever but it will produce strange output if the first value(s) associated with a key are 0.